# Force Visual Studio 2015 to use RC1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

Performed Visual Studio 2015 Update and now MVC 6 project won't compile - missing dependencies. The project was working fine with RC1 but I suspect VS is trying to use RC2.

[image: Visual Studio Errors]

Comment: Have you tried removing the bad references and re-referencing those libraries?

Comment: I have but without success, I think my issue is related to this nuget timeout issue, when I do a dotnet restore it takes an hour and there are tons of "... has timed out after 10000ms"  messages. Before the Visual Studio update this would take less then a minute.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080853/nuget-package-manager-hangs-when-getting-dependencies-in-visual-studio-2015-upda